# managing/implementing auto-increment primary key in oracle without triggers

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy, oracle11g, auto-increment

We have many tables in our database with autoincrement primary key ids setup the way they are in MySQL since we are in the process of migrating to Oracle from MySQL.

Now in oracle I recently learned that implementing this requires creating a sequence and a trigger on the id field for each such table. We have like 30 -40 tables in our schema and we want to avoid using database triggers in our product, since management of database is out of scope for our software appliance.

What are my options in implementing the auto increment id feature in oracle... apart from manually specifying the id in the code and managing it in the code which would change a lot of existing insert statements.

...  I wonder if there is a way to do this from grails code itself?  (by the way the method of specifying id as increment in domain class mapping doesnt work - only works for mysql)
 Some info about our application environement: grails-groovy, hibernate, oracle,mysql support

Comment: What management tasks do you expect to introduce by creating triggers and sequences? Essentially it is identical what is done in MySQL autoincrement but you build it yourself.

Comment: how often would it be that a trigger fails..

Comment: Depends on the code inside. I've never seen a trigger fail for other reasons than problems with the sequences, wich causes failures in the other solution too. Advantage of using a trigger is that the PK generation mechanism not only works for you app but for direct inserts using SQL or other ways/apps inserting data. I often combine the two solutions. Let hibernate do the PK generation in my app and use a trigger that generates a PK when no PK is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336057/901257) will have Grails/Hibernate handle the sequence generation by itself.  It'll create a sequence per table for the primary key generation and won't cache any numbers, so you won't lose any identifiers if and when the cache times out.  Grails/Hibernate calls the sequence directly, so it doesn't make use of any triggers either.

Comment: this is a very good solution... considering all the dependency is inside the configuration...just wondering if the specified dialiect is a custome dialect created from oracle10gdialect?

Comment: Yes.  It's a a custom dialect developed for our work environment.  It's been working great for us as a solution.

Comment: So I implemented the custom dialect... do I need to have sequences created for the tables or the dialect will take care of basically everything? I am not having mapping in the table for the id field also..

Comment: All you have to do is implement the class in your project, such as in `src/java`, and then in your `DataSource.groovy` make sure you are specifying that Grails/Hibernate should use the dialect via `dialect = com.mycompany.CustomDialect`.  It should handle all of the sequence creation itself.  You don't need any mapping specifications in your domain classes, as it will default to a sequence per table for the id field with the dialect.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine, I can add new users from UI and id is managed by grails. But I have another issue with this. Its not working in batch upload of users code which is a different service. I am trying to use the same dataSource there too, but I get exception saying cannot insert null in users.id. I want to know if we need to use hibernate to do the batch inserts? please refer to my other question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826866/inserts-in-database-failing-from-grails-service

Comment: can I only use hibernate to do inserts in my tables if I use this method? .or using this datasource will successfully handle the id auto-increment?

Comment: If you use the Datasource to do straight sql inserts, you will probably have to query the appropriate sequence yourself to get the next primary key id.  Inserting outside of Grails/Hibernate is where an Oracle trigger would come in to play to handle autoincrement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Grails hibernate will handle this for you automatically.

You can specify which sequence to use by putting the following in your domain object:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'MY_SEQ']  
}
```

Comment: No need for triggers. If you ommit the mapping it will work for mysql and Oracle, but it will just use one sequence called hibernate_seq.

Comment: so you mean if I dont have my own sequence defined in oracle and I dont have this mapping in domain, and I insert a new row without specifying id... then the id will still be incremented using internal sequence common for the database which is- hibernate_seq?

Comment: Has anyone followed this article here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333998/grails-sequence-generation-for-oracle-11g/8336057#8336057

Comment: I am not sure to understand previous comments, anyway you can create a simple oracle sequence with tool sql developer and then use it with hibernate. For example:     CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ START WITH 1;   . Just tested it.