# inserts in database failing from grails service

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, datasource

I am using oracle11g as the database, and trying to do inserts into globalusers table from my grails service class. 
I am retrieving the datasource in grails service like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH 
class UserImportService {
 def dataSource = AH.application.mainContext.dataSource
 def sql = new Sql(dataSource) ;
 String insertQuery="insert into GLOBALUSERS (..) values (..)
                try{
                    sql.execute(insertQuery)
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    println "Failed to insert : " +insertQuery
                    println "Exception is:" + e;

                }
}
```

When I run the service from front end I get sql exception saying

```
Exception is:java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("GRA"."GLOBALUSERS"."ID")
```

Since I am using a Datasource with my custom dialect which handles ID generation and autoincrement this should be handled by grail/hibernate.

When use the same datasource from other UI .. one by one.. it works..so the dialect is working fine. but this service for batch updates is not working.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue - you're doing way too much work to get the `dataSource` bean if this is a service in `grails-app/services`. You can skip the applicationholder bit and just have `def dataSource` since you can inject any Spring bean into a service (or other artifacts) with `def <beanname>`.

Comment: Hi...yeah I read your article... but in my controller I am invoking new service() ... what would be that changes overall in changing that? and something related to the question...do I have to persist using domain class only for auto id generation using hibernate, if yes how do I set 72 fields in the globalusers domain class in the fastest way..if no how do I make my code generic for all databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing direct Sql on the `dataSource` bean is going to bypass Hibernate's method of id generation, which, as I understand it, does a `nextval()` on the appropriate Oracle sequence.  So your options are:

- Use Grails/GORM, where you create the object, populate, and `.save()`
- Query the sequence yourself, which would involve doing a `nextval()` on the sequence, but it would make your Sql Oracle-specific
- Add an Oracle trigger to the database, which tests if the primary key is set, and if it isn't does the `nextval()` sequence query and adds it to the new database row.  This will keep your direct Sql compatible with MySql autoincrement and Oracle sequences.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know grails but it seems to me that

- your code doesn't use Hibernate at all. It executes SQL directly
- even if it used Hibernate, using SQL queries in Hibernate completely bypasses ID generation. For automatic ID generation, you would have to instantiate and persist an entity.

Comment: Thanks... So In other words for automatic ID generation I have to use the Domain/Entity class associated with GLOBALUSERS, and there is not other way around this using plain inserts ???

Comment: It all depends on the ID generation strategy. Since you're using Oracle, I guess you're using a sequence for your IDs. You could query the sequence nextval yourself, or even invoke the Hibernate generator explicitely. But I fail to see why you're using Hibernate if your plan is to use native SQL queries.

Comment: For user creation from UI we do use the USERS domain class and its working fine, we are using Hibernate throughout out application for all functionalities related to database, only this is an external userimportservice which imports like 50000 users so for simplicity and speed it was developed using native sql. users table has like 75 columns and setting each attribute for all users to be imported will make it slow, I want to know how do I invoke hibernate generator explicitly, also in the end the script should work for both mysql and oracle, so using nextval() will make it oracle specific?

Comment: Have you measured that it was too slow? If you follow what is said  at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts, I'm pretty sure it won't be much slower than to use SQL inserts.

Comment: ok sounds good, but its a major change.. I want to try explicity invoking hibernate generator before that..