# Strange behaviour of Grails' application connected to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to switch my grails application from h2 to PostgreSQL. 
Steps I've done to reach my goal:

1. Download JDBC from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html (JDBC4 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.3-1100)
2. Attach JDBC to /lib folder
3. Change DataSource. Now it looks like:

   ```
   dataSource {
       pooled = true
       driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
       dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
       username = "postgres"
       password = "admin"
   }
   hibernate {
       cache.use_second_level_cache = true
       cache.use_query_cache = false
       cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
   }
   // environment specific settings
   environments {
       development {
           dataSource {
               dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
               //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
               url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/admin_panel"
           }
       }
       test {
           dataSource {
               dbCreate = "update"
               url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/admin_panel"
           }
       }
       production {
           dataSource {
               dbCreate = "update"
               url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/admin_panel"
               pooled = true
               properties {
                  maxActive = -1
                  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
                  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
                  numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
                  testOnBorrow=true
                  testWhileIdle=true
                  testOnReturn=true
                  validationQuery="SELECT 1"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

And now the game starts. I type 'run-app' in GGTS and I get an error. Objects I'm trying to create using BootStrap cannot be initialized because of Validation: `Error initializing the application: Validation Error(s) occurred during save()` .
It is really strange because the message says that reference to previously created object is null: `Field error in object 'adminpanel.component.Text' on field 'subpage': rejected value [null];`. 
There should be no possibility that "subpage" is null in this line, so I go to the pgAdmin III to check if this record is created and there I notice that no table is created at all.

Everetyhing works if application is connected to H2, but starts to freak out when I switch it to postgres. Additionally, when I remove everything from BootStrap, application starts and I can create objects normally, but I still cannot see them into pgAdmin. Do you have any advice what else can I check or why GORM does not create tables in my app when I use PostgreSQL ?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

I found the source of the problem after few tests more...
PostgreSQL gives a strange value for 'id' column in every table. When I was using H2, I had values from 1..x in every table, in PostgreSQL I have something like this:

```
table1
id:
1
2
3
-
7
8
9

table2
id:
4
5
6
-
10
11
```

As you probably noticed, values are given interchangeably for all rows in different tables, so I cannot have e.g. object table1 with id 1 and object table2 with id 1. Do you have idea why?

Comment: This might help answer some of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580807/hibernate-postgresql-with-grails

Comment: Sounds like something specific to PostgreSQL, but should NOT be a problem for you.  Each object has an id column but the value should not really matter and your code should not be dependent on something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I know it does not change much for me, but I had some objects to test my changes, and creating of them was quite static, just for me - developer. In the code I had something like new Text(subpage: Subpage.get(1));. As I wrote above, in H2 I had ids from 1 to n, right now they seem to be unique in whole database. This where my error in BootStrap come from :)

Answer (score 2):

Grails/Hibernate uses `Sequence` for object ID for databases like Postgres (or Oracle, etc). By default, Grails uses a shared sequence (`hibernate_sequence`). So all object will have uniq id, but unique per whole database, not per table.

You can configure domain to use a different Sequence for a domain, like:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'my_own_sequence']
}
```

See also

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createsequence.html
- http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html